# Open Chrome 'new tab' with a particular url

Tags: google-chrome

When I open a new tab in Chrome, I want to have it load particular URL.

I can see how to set a home page, and how to tell it what to do on startup -- but not how to load a page for new tabs.

How can I make it do this? Is it possible?

Comment: You would have to add an extension to do this....https://www.howtogeek.com/284582/how-to-open-a-new-tab-to-a-specific-webpage-in-your-browser/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just worked for me!

1. Create a Chrome extension (or you can use one that you've already coded).
2. Inside the `manifest.json`, include:

```
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "newTabOverride.html"
    }
```

3. In the root folder of your extension, create a `newTabOverride.html` file that contains only this line: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/" />`

<sub>*(I followed instructions from @PredatorIWD's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269892/470749); I don't know why it was deleted. Maybe because it doesn't leave the cursor in the URL field to allow for a Google search.)*</sub>

Also, you might want to just install an existing extension, if you trust it: https://github.com/jimschubert/NewTab-Redirect

Comment: If you open Secure Preferences in your user folder AppData under Chrome\Default, you can set it manually. It's a bit finicky about syntax, but it's doable if you're careful.

Comment: @Didier I hadn't heard of `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Secure Preferences`. It would be interesting to see detailed instructions about it.

Comment: I take it it's a hidden file, but it does show up in Search for any Chromium-based browser. I guess it's not supposed to be edited by users, but I learned a thing or two just by reading its content in Opera and Vivaldi. I suppose Chrome has one too.

Answer (score 4):

There are some extensions for that. It's the easiest option, search with 'new tab override' keyword. Here's a random example from Chrome Store. Try it.
[Custom New Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-new-tab-url/mmjbdbjnoablegbkcklggeknkfcjkjia)

If you don't want to rely on third part, I've also found manual instructions on Stack Overflow.
[Override the Chrome new tab page with a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46374281/9779791)

And also small video for that extension to code with.
[Chrome Extensions: New Tab Override - Programming with Text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNb3P5KIxXw)

Comment: This seems to be a relevant answer but note that simply including links is discouraged. Please improve this answer by including at least some basic process by which the Asker can accomplish his goal (assuming that it is possible to do so).

Answer (score -1):

about:blank

This is not an override of the Chrome's New Tab html (about://newtab or chrome://newtab).